# docker volume issue inside jenkins steps

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Inside a jenkins stage and steps, I am trying to build an image; run the container with a volume and then stash a file in order to unstash it after.
But unfortunately it doesn't create the volume and doesn't stash.

Here is the jenkins code

```
stage('Android') {
          agent {
            label buildLabel()
          }
          steps {
            checkout scm
            sh '''
              mkdir -p `pwd`/build_target
              docker build -t android_build -f docker/Dockerfile.android .
              docker run --rm -v `pwd`/build_target:/home/gradle/reactapp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/ android_build
              ls -la `pwd`/build_target/*
            '''
            stash includes: 'build_target/app-release.apk', name: 'apk'
            androidApkUpload apkFilesPattern: '**/app-release.apk', googleCredentialsId: 'jenkins_apk_upload', trackName: 'internal'
          }

        }
```

Comment: What is the output of `docker build`?  Also, remember that the context for docker build is where the Dockerfile is located. That means that anything in the parent directory of your 'docker' dir won't be part of the build context and won't be accessible to docker build.

Comment: Hi @Alkaline. The output of the dockerfile is an apk (android). You said that it won't be accessible, even if with a volume?

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be configuring a ENV in Global properties on http://jenkins-server/configure.
[image]

In build script, I can use the env to get the shared path in the host.
[image]

And in all agent hosts, I mount the same NFS path to it.
 `mount -t nfs 10.6.188.1:/root /root/pacotest1`
on every node

Comment: Do you have any example? Because i can't really see what is the difference with stash/unstash

Comment: @YoussefHarkati I add some screen shot to do so